# How to serialize a pyspark Pipeline object?

Tags: python, apache-spark, serialization, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to serialize a PySpark `Pipeline` object so that it can be saved and retrieved later. Tried using the Python pickle library as well as the PySpark's `PickleSerializer`, the `dumps()` call itself is failing.

Providing the code snippet while using native `pickle` library.

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, lr])
with open ('myfile', 'wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(pipeline,f,2)
with open ('myfile', 'rb') as f:
   pipeline1 = pickle.load(f)
```

Getting the below error while running:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o32.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

Is it possible to serialize PySpark `Pipeline` objects ?

Comment: You can use mleap

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking you can easily pickle `Pipeline` object:

```
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Pipeline
import pickle

pickle.dumps(Pipeline(stages=[]))
## b'\x80\x03cpyspark.ml.pipeline\nPipeline\nq ...
```

What you cannot pickle is Spark `Transformers` and `Estimators` which are only thin wrappers around JVM objects. If you really need this you can wrap this in a function for example:

```
def make_pipeline():
    return Pipeline(stages=[Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")])

pickle.dumps(make_pipeline)
## b'\x80\x03c__ ...
```

but since it is just a piece of code and doesn't store any persistent data it doesn't look particularly useful.

Comment: This works when I try to work with an empty Pipeline object - pickle.dumps(Pipeline(stages=[])), however when I try to pickle a Pipeline object with stages, it still fails. Tried the method format you proposed, but if I try pickle.dumps(make_pipeline()), it still fails with the same error.

Comment: And I will :) Take another look at my code `pickle.dumps(make_pipeline)`   and yours `pickle.dumps(make_pipeline)`. I only pickle an object which can be used to generate Pipeline, no Pipeline itself.